# Handling Active Directory events in Java/C#

Tags: java, c#, events, active-directory

I want to create an C# or Java application in which I would like to handle some specific A.D events such as 4725 (a user account was disabled) or any other event.

When a specific event occurs I would like to read some of the event's details such as EventID, TargetAccountName, etc.

Can you guide me to some APIs and some tutorials/ explanations regarding the best way to implement what I described above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find a lot of infos about event handling in c#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671204(v=vs.90).aspx